# Sending HTTPS Requests through an upstream proxy with Fiddler

Tags: https, proxy, fiddler

I already checked [Fiddler - tunnelled http requests to port 443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171277/fiddler-tunnelled-http-requests-to-port-443) and [Fiddler2: Decrypt HTTPS traffic and Tunnel to host:443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793737/fiddler2-decrypt-https-traffic-and-tunnel-to-host443), but my question is different.

I do not want to use Fiddler as a Proxy for another program. Instead, I simply want to use Fiddler's Composer Tab to send a HTTPS request over an upstream proxy. My proxy configuration and authorization is correct; sending HTTP requests works just fine.

When I use Fiddler's Composer to send an HTTPS GET to https://google.com, it results in a time-out (HTTP 502 / [Fiddler] The connection to 'google.com' failed. Error: TimedOut (0x274c).).

When I send an HTTPS CONNECT to https://google.com, I get HTTP 502 / [Fiddler] DNS Lookup for failed.
                                                                                Does anybody know how I can establish an HTTPS tunnel over my proxy and then send a GET request?

Answer (score 0):

to establish the tunnel, you must use CONNECT to the proxy.  You must also include the host header, which doubles the destination in the CONNECT request... e.g.

```
CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
etc
```

Once the tunnel is up (e.g. you get a 200 OK from the proxy) you need to go into TLS handshake before you can send the http request (which since it's over TLS is now https).  e.g.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
etc.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, my proxy never answers 200 OK, but always 502. Anyway, I am using cURL now, which works as expected.

Comment: Yes, it's telling you it doesn't like something about your request.  there are minimum requirements for any http request, including CONNECT, such as a valid Host header.  If you didn't have it in there, it would fail, and I could easily see it failing to resolve an empty name giving as you said "DNS lookup for failed"